# Math software for symbolic computation with customizable rules.

Tags: math-software

I am looking for software where we can define operations and rules of manipulation. For example, defining multiplication of $x,y \in A$ to be $x\cdot y:= xy-yx$ and $x^{2k}=1$ and $y^{3k}=1$, $\forall k \gt 0$. Also, we should be able to impose commutativity or non-commutativity, etc... I have heard of mathematica, maple, sagemath,.. , but I don't know which of those can accomplish what I want. Please give me some recommendations.

Comment: Mathematica can do almost anything that you might want to do symbolically using your own custom rules and many built-in functions.

Comment: awesome. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have some experience with Maple. It allows to define functions such as

> $f := (x,y)\mapsto xy-yx$

and to manipulate and simplify expressions

> simplify(f,{x^2=xy,y^2=yx}$

These belong to the standard capabilities of computer algebra systems.

Comment: what about imposing non-commutativity and non-associativity and other rules?

Comment: Non-commutativity holds in the first place. You have to specify $xy=yx$ to establish commutativity. Same for associativity.